# Java jax-rs server

Tags: java, web-services, rest

When I locally test SOAP web services I made, I usually do this:

```
MyServiceImpl service = new MyServiceImpl();
Endpoint endpoint=Endpoint.create(service);
endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8084/service") ;
```

now I want to expand this to REST services as well.
I can do this with JBoss, but I want to test locally before as well.
Is there any way I can start Jax-RS Rest HTTP service within Java (and no other 3rd party libs, like jersey etc..)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without adding in dependencies. Easy way is the Simple Framework and jersey-simple-server. Add them in a profile in maven and you can still deploy to JBoss without them.

Comment: I already have my Http server, but I would like to skip as much as possible dependincies. Since Im making it for Jboss, I will check within Jboss library if it has already such methods.

Comment: What http server are you using?

Comment: I have my own Tracy, wanted somehow to use JBoss like endpoint, as I need JBoss library already for development. As there is java.ws library integrated to start http soap server up, I assume there must be also for http rest servlet

Answer (score 0):

You can open http connection by manual, a lots of way to do this

Below is one of more example.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.sum.com/");
        URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```